# Batch programming, stop and start services

Tags: windows-services, batch-file

It is save to terminate the services using **taskkill** when the attempt to stop using **NET STOP** was failed? And if i terminate it using taskkill, do **NET START** command will affect or do i need to use **START** command?

consider this code as example:

```
@ECHO OFF
:STOP
NET STOP someservices
IF ERRORLEVEL == 0 GOTO :START
GOTO :KILL

:START
NET START someservices

:KILL
TASKKILL /F /IM someservices.exe
SLEEP 10
START someservices.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SC instead of NET -- it won't fail.

Billy3

EDIT: And you will have difficulty killing a fair number of services which can share the same process.
EDIT2: See this for more details -> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314056

Comment: "And you will have difficulty killing a fair number of services which can share the same process" which one? SC or NET?

Comment: Either. Many windows services share the same svchost.exe process.